# Where is the old Kotlin specification hosted?

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to find the old version of Kotlin site (jetbrains.com/kotlin) with the old documentation. I saw it somewhere on the internet not so long ago, but now I can not find it.

Please, point me to the location, or, if it's offline, it would be helpfull to get a backup copy.

I need that specification to compare the standard through the versions (M6, M8, M10). Additionaly, there were some interesting discussions in the comments, it would be a pity to lost them. Thanks

Comment: FYI: these are just user docs, not a spec

Comment: why don't they just let pick the version when browsing documentation like python does? https://docs.python.org/3/library/ Is there a difference in how they version their language that makes this impossible or do they just assume there is never a need to look up specific things in old documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: It seems to no longer be available.

<s>https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/Kotlin/Welcome This may be what you're looking for.</s>

Comment: egrrr, they moved it! Don't know where

Comment: I think with the advent of 1.0, they may have gotten rid of their older documentation.

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/category/releases/

These posts can be used to follow the changes that happened in every version since M1. They don't contain the same discussions in the comments, but they do have their own comments.

I hope that's good enough to help you out.